# How to tell Mathematica to replace 0 to power 0 by 1?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Experts;

Given

```
f = (#1^#2) &
```

Is there a way to define 'f' above such that if #1 *and* #2 are both zero, then the value of the pure function 'f' should be 1 ?

so that when I write

```
f[0,0]
```

it will return 1 and not Indeterminate?

btw, I know I can write

```
f = (If[#1 == 0 && #2 == 0, 1, #1^#2]) &
```

But I wanted a general rule or pattern, so I do not have to write these checks, as the pure function can be more complicated (many # in it ) and I do not want to do many of these 'if then else' checks for each possible 0^0 that might show up.

thanks

**Update:**

May be I should clarify more why I am doing this.
I have a user selects a function from a menu. The function is

```
a x^n0 + b y^n1 + c x^n2 y^n3
```

Where in the above, the parameters 'n0', 'n1', 'n2' and 'n3' also can be selected from sliders, and these can be zero.

Now, 'x' and 'y' are coordinates, and these can be zero also.

Therefore, it is possible that 0^0 can be encountered when evaluating the above function.

There are many cases to check for, when doing it myself. For example 'y^n3' can be 0^0 and not the other, y^n1 can be 0^0 and not the other, x^n2 y^n3 can be both 0^0 and not the others, etc.., and so I have to define many different cases. (16 possible cases I think).

And I am trying to avoid this. If I can tell Mathematica to replace 0^0 by 1 at a lower level, then life will be simpler.

**Update 12/7/11**
Thanks for everyone's answers and comments, all are very useful and solve my problem and I learned from them.

I selected Leonid answer as it allowed me to solve my problem with least amount of additional coding.

Here is an small example

```
Manipulate[Row[{format[x, n], "=", eval[x, n]}],
 {{x, 0.0, "x="}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{n, 0.0, "n="}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :>
  (
   format[x_, n_] := HoldForm["(" x ")"^n];
   eval = Unevaluated[#1^#2] /. HoldPattern[0.0^0.0] :> 0.0 &
   )
 ]
```

I use real numbers everywhere in my code (it is a numerical pde solver), so that is why I used 0.0 in the above and not 0^0 to fit with what I am doing.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want these to eval to 1 and not 0? The notation makes it look as though you are evaluating polynomials where the exponents are nonnegative ints or perhaps reals. Continuity considerations would indicate that a value of 0 might be preferable in that scenario.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Ok, thanks, will look into 0^0 be replaced by 0 instead of 1. But either case, if I use IF THEN ELSE (or its functional equivalent by defining many different signatures for each possible case), there are still 16 different cases. Was hoping there is a way to short circuit this, but telling Mathematica to replace 0^0 by X where X is the correct choice (0 or 1 as it might be).

Comment: See also this mathgroup discussion: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6577581&tstart=0 and this question on the programmers SE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/how-does-language-x-handle-indeterminate-forms-like-00

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with the answer of @Deep Yellow, but if you insist on a pure function, here is one way:

```
f = Unevaluated[#1^#2] /. HoldPattern[0^0] :> 1 &
```

*EDIT*

Staying within the realm of pure functions, the situation you described in your edit can be addressed in the same way as my solution to your specific original example. You can automate this with a tiny bit of metaprogramming, defining the following function transformer:

```
z2zProtect[Function[body_]] := 
   Function[Unevaluated[body] /. HoldPattern[0^0] :> 1]
```

Then, my previous code can be rewritten as:

```
 f = z2zProtect[#1^#2 &]
```

But you can is this more generally, for example:

```
ff = z2zProtect[#1^#2 + 2 #2^#3 + 3 #3^#4 &]

In[26]:= ff[0,0,0,0]
Out[26]= 6
```

Comment: +1 Nice, although let me point out that `f[foo, 0]` returns `1` for undefined `foo`.

Comment: @Deep Yellow Thanks for the upvote. Regarding your comment - this is as expected, and is based on a built-in rule for `Power`, not on my particular definition. Your solution exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Oh yeah :-) *Mathematica* assumes undefined expressions aren't equal to zero for `Power`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks, will try your Protect meta solution in my program, as it seems it will work,  Will update with what I find later today.

Answer (score 17):

Of course there are many ways to do things in *Mathematica*, but a design idiom I often use is to write the "function" (actually, a pattern) with decreasing specificity.  *Mathematica* has the property that it will apply more specific patterns before less specific.

So, for your case I'd just write:

```
Clear[f];
f[0, 0] = 1;
f[a_, b_] := a^b;
```

I assume you expect to work with integer values since that's the usual context for this type of situation, e.g. when evaluating Bernstein basis functions.

Comment: +1 Good, clear answer with no frills. BTW,I think you meant to say "with decreasing specificity".

Answer (score 4):

You may try writing it like `f = Quiet[Check[#1^#2,1]] &`.

`Quiet` will suppress the `"Power::indet: "Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered."` message and `Check` will replace the result with `1` if it is indeterminate.

It is probably better to use some function like `s = Quiet[Check[#1, 1]]` and wrap your expressions in it.

Comment: Note that this will also suppress everything that produces the same error and output 1, irrespective of whether that's the desired outcome. For example, `f[0,I]`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly surprised the trivial (albeit slightly dangerous) fix did not get mentioned earlier. If you really don't expect the expression `0^0` to come up in any context where you'd (a) be worried that it did, or (b) would like it to evaluate it to something other than 1, you can simply try

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
0^0
```

I needed this fix in a situation where a complicated function had a number of calls to expressions of the form `x^n` where `x` is real and `n` is an integer, in which case `0^0` should be seen as the limit of `x^0=1` as `x` goes to 0.

It's important to note, though, that doing this will 'contaminate' `Power` for the current kernel session, and may therefore break other notebooks which run concurrently and for which conditions (a) and (b) may not hold. Since `Power` is located in the `System՝` context instead of `Global՝`, it may be difficult to separate the contexts of different notebooks to avoid clashes produced by this fix.

Comment: This should be the default.